# Dart build runner generate one dart file with content

Tags: dart

I am working on a dart package with includes over 200 models and at the moment i have to write manually one line of "export" for each model, to make the models available for everyone who uses this package.

I want the build runner to generate one dart file which contains every export definition.

Therefore I would create an annotation "ExportModel". The builder should search for each class annotated with this annotation.

I tried creating some Builders, but they will generate a *.g.dart file for each class that is annotated. I just want to have one file.

Is where a way to create a builder that runs only once and creates a file at the end ?

Comment: Are you using package:build directly or (I'm guessing) package:source_gen? Are you using a SharedPartBuilder or a LibraryBuilder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer to your question of a builder that only runs once and creates a single file in the package is to use `r'$lib$'` as the input extension. The long answer is that to find the classes that are annotated you probably want an intermediate output to track them.

I'd write this with 2 builders, one to search for the `ExportModel` annotation, and another to write the exports file. Here is a rough sketch with details omitted - I haven't tested any of the code here but it should get you started on the right path.

#### Builder 1 - find the classes annotated with `@ExportModel()`.

Could write with some utilities from `package:source_gen`, but can't use `LibraryBuilder` since it's not outputting Dart code...

Goal is to write a `.exports` file next to each `.dart` file which as the name of all the classes that are annotated with `@ExportModel()`.

```
class ExportLocatingBuilder implements Builder {
  @override
  final buildExtensions = const {
    '.dart': ['.exports']
  };

  @override
  Future<void> build(BuildStep buildStep) async {
    final resolver = buildStep.resolver;
    if (!await resolver.isLibrary(buildStep.inputId)) return;
    final lib = LibraryReader(await buildStep.inputLibrary);
    final exportAnnotation = TypeChecker.fromRuntime(ExportModel);
    final annotated = [
      for (var member in lib.annotatedWith(exportAnnotation)) element.name,
    ];
    if (annotated.isNotEmpty) {
      buildStep.writeAsString(
          buildStep.inputId.changeExtension('.exports'), annotated.join(','));
    }
  }
}
```

This builder should be `build_to: cache` and you may want to have a `PostProcessBuilder` that cleans up all the outputs it produces which would be specified with `applies_builder`. You can use the [`FileDeletingBuilder`](https://pub.dev/documentation/build/latest/build/FileDeletingBuilder-class.html) to cheaply implement the cleanup. See [the FAQ](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/builder_author_faq.md#how-can-i-have-temporary-outputs-only-used-during-the-build) on temporary outputs and the [angular cleanup](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/8766b0d9be71c0f88367d69371b73775e317205e/angular/lib/src/build.dart#L101-L104) for example.

#### Builder 2 - find the `.exports` files and generate a Dart file

Use [`findAssets`](https://pub.dev/documentation/build/latest/build/AssetReader/findAssets.html) to track down all those `.exports` files, and write an `export` statement for each one. Use a `show` with the content of the file which should contain the names of the members that were annotated.

```
class ExportsBuilder implements Builder {
  @override
  final buildExtensions = const {
    r'$lib$': ['exports.dart']
  };

  @override
  Future<void> build(BuildStep buildStep) async {
    final exports = buildStep.findAssets(Glob('**/*.exports'));
    final content = [
      await for (var exportLibrary in exports)
        'export \'${exportLibrary.changeExtension('.dart').uri}\' '
            'show ${await buildStep.readAsString(exportLibrary)};',
    ];
    if (content.isNotEmpty) {
      buildStep.writeAsString(
          AssetId(buildStep.inputId.package, 'lib/exports.dart'),
          content.join('\n'));
    }
  }
}
```

This builder should likely be `build_to: source` if you want to publish this file on pub. It should have a `required_inputs: [".exports"]` to ensure it runs after the previous builder.

#### Why does it need to be this complex?

You *could* implement this as a single builder which uses `findAssets` to find all the Dart files. The downside is that rebuilds would be much slower because it would be invalidated by any content change in any Dart file and you'd end up parsing *all* Dart code for a change in *any* Dart code. With the 2 builder approach then only the individual `.exports` which come from a changed Dart file need to be resolved and rebuilt on a change, and then only if the exports change will the `exports.dart` file be invalidated.

Older versions of `build_runner` also didn't support using the `Resolver` to resolve code that isn't transitively imported from the input library. Recent version of `build_runner` have relaxed this constraint.

Comment: will give it a try the next few days! You will get feedback soon.

Comment: There's some awesome information in this answer. Any chance this example is in a public repo?